# Comparing array elements using mathematical symbols in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A`. I am comparing `A[i+1]=A[i]` but the current output is in terms of 0's and 1's. Instead I want it to give in terms of `< or = or >`. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([np.array([[0.01609   , 0.01728839, 0.01635707],
              [0.01696908, 0.01661592, 0.0163007 ],
              [0.01609   , 0.01642818, 0.01950431]]),
       np.array([[[0.01609   , 0.01728839, 0.01635707],
               [0.01696908, 0.01661592, 0.0163007 ],
               [0.01609   , 0.01642818, 0.01950431]]]),
       np.array([[[0.01609   , 0.017286  , 0.01635698],
               [0.01698125, 0.01659415, 0.01630078],
               [0.01627952, 0.01639007, 0.01951677]]])], dtype=object)


for i in range(0,len(A)-1):
    B=(A[i+1]==A[i]).astype(int)
    print([B])
```

The current output is

```
[array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]])]
[array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])]
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[=, =, =],
        [=, =, =],
        [=, =, =]]])]
[array([[[=, <, <],
        [>, <, >],
        [>, <, >]]])]
```

Comment: There is a convention to represent the expected output numerically `for i in range(1,len(A)): print(np.sign(A[i]-A[i-1]))` or `np.sign(A[1:]-A[:-1])` for typable arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `np.select`

```
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    B = np.select([A[i+1]==A[i],A[i+1]>A[i],A[i+1]<A[i]], ["=",">","<"])
    print([B])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the for loop using [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```py
mapping = {
    "<": A[1:] < A[:-1],
    "=": A[1:] == A[:-1],
    ">": A[1:] > A[:-1],
}

choicelist, condlist = zip(*mapping.items())

result = np.select(condlist, choicelist)

# equivalent to
# result = np.select(mapping.values(), mapping.keys())
```

```py
>>> result
array([[['=', '=', '='],
        ['=', '=', '='],
        ['=', '=', '=']],

       [['=', '<', '<'],
        ['>', '<', '>'],
        ['>', '<', '>']]], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: Broadcasting can't be used with ragged input arrays (like the example)

Comment: Yes I assumed it was a ragged array because of bad formatting, because with the shapes given it is not necessary for A to be ragged.

Comment: I agree (+1), this should be the preferred solution in almost all similar cases.